# TWClass not found

Tags: ibm-bpm

There exists all needed types, but it seem bpm don't refresh process data on own db.
How to solve?

Error: **The execution context was not saved due to the following error**: **TWClass with ID TWClass.4dc49e76-5339-46bf-8622-e8e58cfa163f not found**.

Comment: It seems that you are referencing a class/business error that is no longer there. On the failing step, can you see a variable with a waring, or do you get any hints of validation errors?

Comment: yes, it was a problem **referencing a class/business error that is no longer there**  But it seems there is no way to find problem easily. I look through all BO parameters and then found. Thank you for answer.

Comment: You are welcome, as the comment was helpful, I copied it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are referencing a class/business error that is no longer there. On the failing step, you should see a warning or a validation error.

Answer (score 1):

TWClass is always a Business Object which has lost its reference.

Please check all the variables whether they are mapped to corresponding BO.